# Using base class operators for derived classes in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11, operator-keyword

Consider the example.

I have a container class (`A`), which overloads/implements all kinds of arithmetic operators (`A::negate()`).

I now wish to create derived classes (`B` and `C`).

`B` and `C` should have all operators implemented by `A`.

**However, those operators should use derived-class objects as arguments.**

The prototype for `B::negate` should be: `B B::negate()`, instead of the `A B::negate()`.

The derived classes do not need any own fields, but may implement own methods (`B::foo()`, `C::bar()`).
It is a requirement that `B` and `C` be incompatible, i.e., a `B` object can not be assigned to a `C` object, or used with any of `C`'s operators.

Here is the example code, how I want it to work:

```
struct A {
        int val;

        A negate() {
                return A{-val};
        }
};

struct B: A {void foo(){}};
struct C: A {void bar(){}};

int main() {
        B obj0 = {5};
        B obj1 = obj0.negate();
}
```

I understand that this is probably impossible using standard inheritance, and might be something C++11 simply isn't capable of, so I'm asking for something as close as possible to it.

The currently best solution I've come up with involves not using inheritance at all, but instead adding an integer template parameter to the base class, defining derived classes as `using B = A<1>;`,`using C = A<2>;`, and implementing member methods only for some specializations (only `A::foo<1>(){}` and `A::bar<2>(){}`).

However, I'm highly unhappy with this solution.

Comment: Have you looked into the Curiously recurring template pattern? The template parameter you want to pass is the class itself, i.e. `struct B : A<B>`, that's how Boost.Operators works (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm)

Comment: filmor: after just staring at `struct B: A<B>` for a few minutes, this appears more and more genius. Possibly far too genius for my overtired mind to grasp right now.

Comment: You can search the Intarwebs for the name, it might even be enough to search on StackOverflow. Besides, the code given by Yakk implements it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<typename Child>
struct A {
  Child* self() {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< A<Child>, Child >::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<Child*>(this);
  }
  Child const* self() const {
    static_assert( std::is_base_of< A<Child>, Child >::value, "CRTP failure" );
    return static_cast<Child const*>(this);
  }
  Child negate() {
    return Child{-val};
  }
};
struct B:A<B> {
  explicit B(int v):A<B>(v) {}
};
```

here, we inject information into the base class `template` about its child.  `B` is then relatively free to be a normal class.

In the parent, you can get `self()` in order to access your `this` pointer as a `B` (or other derived class).

Another approach involves free functions.  You write a free `negate` `template` function that checks if its argument is derived from `A`, and if so does the negate action, and returns the negative version of the type passed in.

A mixture of these also works, where your free function takes `A<D>`s and returns a `D`.

Comment: Yeah, I should not have doubted C++'s ability to be capable of something. However, I'm wondering why I would want to access my `this` pointer as `B`? At least in the scenario I described in my question, I wouldn't, right?

Comment: @mic_e Suppose you want different behavior in your `A<B>` than in your `A<C>`.  You could call a `virtual` function that you override in  your child classes -- this has virtual call overhead, and a rigid interface.  Alternatively, you could just call a non-virtual `self()->blah` method.  That will statically at compile time be routed to the `B::blah` or `C::blah` method.

Comment: @mic_e Next, suppose you have a method like `+=`.  This returns `*this` traditionally.  But you want to return `Child`.  So you can return `*self()`, and allow the `static_cast` to child to occur in there.

Comment: Wouldn't the static_cast automatically be done when just writing `return *this`?

Comment: Also, is there a way of avoiding having to stating the explicit constructor each time?

Comment: @mic_e no, because `*this` is `A<B>`, and `B` is a child type of `A<B>`!  You can `using` parent constructors in C++11 in `B` which is a bit less error prone and less boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

Covariant return types:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual A& operator ! () { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

struct B : public A {
    virtual B& operator ! () { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; return *this; }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    A* a = &b;
    ! *a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use templates:

Make A::negate() protected.

In B:

```
struct B : public A
{
   B & negate()
   {
      A:negate();
      return *this
   }
  /// and so on
}
```

Because negate is defined in B, it totally hides the negate defined in A so the B implementation gets called and can delegate to A.

If you plan to hide ALL of A from the user, then B should contain an A rather than inheriting from it.  (make A::negate public again)

```
struct B
{
   private:
   A m_a;
  public:
   B & negate()
   {
      m_a.negate();
      return *this
   }
  /// and so on
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I do really want to avoid adding code for all (over 20) operators for every derived class. This could easily sum up to hundreds, if not thousands of lines of redundant code in my case.